# ArcPro Python Package Manager not installing packages

Tags: python, esri

I am working with ESRI ArcPro 2.9 and would like to install some additional python packages through the Python Package Manager. I've created a clone and made sure that is the default for the Project Environment.  However, when I select a package like opencv, click install, and accept the terms and conditions, the progress bar runs for a bit then just stops without ever installing the package.  I've tried restarting the software and computer but neither helps. Only way I've been able to install additional packages is through conda but this isn't always the answer as it causes some issues with dependencies. Have any of you run into this problem as well and how have you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out after speaking with ESRI over a couple of days. It is apparently just a glitch in the software when this happens.  In order to install a package you need to use the command prompt, navigate to where the conda executable is located and enter either `conda install -c name_of_package` or `conda install -c conda-forge name_of_package`.  The command prompt for me looked like this:`C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts> conda install -c spyder`.  I hope this helps someone else if they have the same problem.